# How to dynamically create an escape sequence?

Tags: c++, escaping, character, sequence

I'm trying to make a program that can dynamically form an escape sequence character.
Please take a look at my code below.

```
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){

    string escapeSeq;
    escapeSeq.push_back('\\');
    escapeSeq.push_back((char)key);
    
    string text = "Hello" + escapeSeq + "World";
    cout << text << endl;
}
```

For example, If I press 'n' key, I'm expecting it to print out

> Hello
>
> World

But it actually prints out

> Hello\nWorld

How can I make the program work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to create and maintain a lookup table, that maps escape sequences to their actual character codes.

Escape sequences in string literals *are evaluated at compile time, by the compiler*. As such, futzing around with code, trying to create them at runtime, is not going to result in anything productive. So you really have no choice but something along the lines of:

```
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){

    string escapeSeq;

    switch (key) {
    case 'n':
       escapeSeq.push_back('\n');
       break;
    case 'r':
       escapeSeq.push_back('\r');
       break;

    // Try to think of every escape sequence you wish to support
    // (there aren't really that many of them), and handle them
    // in the same fashion. 

    default:

       // Unknown sequence. Your original code would be as good
       // of a guess, as to what to do, as anything else...

       escapeSeq.push_back('\\');
       escapeSeq.push_back((char)key);
    }

    string text = "Hello" + escapeSeq + "World";
    cout << text << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must actually write such a dynamic escape character parser yourself. Here's a very simple version:

```
char escape(char c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case 'b': return '\b';
    case 't': return '\t';
    case 'n': return '\n';
    case 'f': return '\f';
    case 'r': return '\r';
    // Add more cases here
    default: // perform some error handling
}
```